# How to resolve error while trying to publish 2013 workflow via designer. Probably a workflow manager backend user account issue?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am getting error while publishing the 2013 workflow via designer. Also, under sharepoint designer if I try to delete any workflow then the page just refreshes and the workflow does not get deleted.

I checked the services.msc and found that the workflow backend service was stopped. (this happened as the password of the user under which this serivce was running had changed).

So, the network admin changed the service user to LOCAL SYSTEM and started the service.

Now, the workflow backend service is started. We have also ran the iisreset.

However, I am still getting the same error:-

*System.IO.InvalidDataException: A response was returned that did not come from the Workflow Manager. Status code = 503: Service Unavailable
Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
Client ActivityId : ee94689c-4e08-b055-fe9c-268d7a94
Please find attached snapshot.*

**Is the error as a result of the change in service user? Can you tell me what priviledges should the account running the workflow backend service must have?**

[image]

**UPDATE 1**
We have tried to set the account to farm admin and also tried to set it to site admin. Now, for a new web application, I can delete workflows. However, for existing site, I am  not able to delete the existing workflows.. Also, I am not able to publish workflows (present under new and previous sites) and the error is same as described earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open IIS and make sure identify of the WorkflowMgmtPool is correct, you can re-type the identify. Then  make this pool is started.

Check and reenter credentials for:- 
Open Services.msc, find Service Bus Message Broker service and Windows Fabric Host Service. Make sure they are running. If not, firstly, start Windows Fabric Host Service, then start Service Bus Message Broker service. If Service Bus Message Broker service is started, stop and re-start it.

Reference- [this forum link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7097f442-1b6f-4656-b0b8-04392dfa6a12/error-while-trying-to-publish-2013-workflow-via-designer-probably-a-workflow-manager-backend-user?forum=sharepointadmin#19ea0bd8-3d43-441c-aada-06033c0b8476)

Answer (score 0):

This error occur because you have not registered the workflow correctly. Re-register the workflow and it will get solved. Also make sure you have activated the App management Service in your site features. 
http://designerworkflow.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

Workflow Manager CU2 to get to 1.0 Refresh in Web Platform installer worked first time for me!
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2902007/en-us

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.

I was able to resolve it by going to IIS on my application server, editing the identity on the Workflow Management Application Pool, saving it and restarting it. I also restarted the server.